# builtins.StopIteration: 2 and json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2) errors

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have a JSON file I am trying to import into MongoDB.

Using the python code from the [documentation][1], I get an error on `myDict = json.loads(jsonObj)` (see traceback below). I have used an online tool to validate my JSON and it is marked as valid. The problem seems to be in line 2 but I have no idea what to do to make this work. Please help!

Python traceback:

````
  obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)

builtins.StopIteration: 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

File "/Users/s/Documents/s/importToMongo.py", line 13, in <module>
  myDict = json.loads(jsonObj)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
  raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)```

**My JSON:** 
```[
    {
        "field1": "6405441",
        "field9": "326",
        "field10": "12",
        "field17": "1180",
        "field22": "Avenue Brugmann",
        "field23": "Brugmannlaan",
        "field24": null,
        "field28": "Uccle",
        "field29": "Ukkel",
        "field30": null,
        "field13": "648301.355 666355.729"
    },
    {
        "field1": "fid",
        "field9": "housenumber",
        "field10": "boxnumber",
        "field17": "postal_info_objectid",
        "field22": "streetname_fr",
        "field23": "streetname_nl",
        "field24": "streetname_de",
        "field28": "municipality_fr",
        "field29": "municipality_nl",
        "field30": "municipality_de",
        "field13": "position"
    }
]```


  [1]: https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/json-to-mongodb
````

Comment: Possibly an encoding problem?  The second character is where the failure would likely occur if the file was saved as UTF-16 or UCS2, but is being read as UTF-8 or other 8-bit encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was this code only works for JSON objects with this format:

- No brackets ( [] )
- No commas at the end of the last field-value pair
- Only one object

Example:

```
{
   "field1":"value",
   "field2":"value"
}
```